# Define window based on bill day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our bill days vary depending on the client.  As i need to track a client by reporting period, I'd like to adjust the parameters automatically.  This information will populate a report.

The bolow code does not work, but illustrates what I would like to achieve:

```
declare @BillDate int
set @BillDate = 18

if @billdate > DATEPART(dd, getdate()) 
    select DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()) ++ DATEPART(mm,getdate()) ++ @BillDate  --last bill date
else
    select DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()) ++ DATEPART(mm,getdate())-1 ++ @BillDate  --last bill date
```

I have also thought about adding a month using `dateadd()`, but I would need to change the day part of day, which I am unsure how to do.

Is there a generally accepted way to do this?  Both my ideas seem like hacks at best.

Edit/update: I'll be using this to filter by in a where clause, so:

```
declare @LastBillDate date, @billday as int
select @billday = billdate from btable where customer = 'Cust'

--Define @LastBillDate here based on getdate() and @billday

SELECT *
FROM atable
WHERE starttime > @LastBillDate
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would better illustrate what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select statement as below:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(yyyy, getdate()),'-',DATEPART(mm,getdate()),'-',@BillDate)
```